# Escaping Quote for Variable in SQL Call

Tags: php, sql

How do you add a single quote to a variable within a SQL statement?  If I put 'jeremy' in place of the '\$user'\ variable it works perfectly.  I can't figure out how to escape the quote for the variable in the SQL statement. Thank you for your help.

```
  $resultArticles = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM articleList WHERE user = '\$user'\ ");
  $totalArticlesLeaderboard = mysql_result($resultArticles, 0);
  echo "<strong>Total Articles: </strong>" . $totalArticlesLeaderboard;
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: What PeeHaa says. But to answer the question, you are looking for `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Comment: @PeeHaa - That could be turned into a really good answer with a bit of work...

Comment: what are the backslashes (`\\`)?

Comment: @DavidStratton It's more like that I am looking for a suited duplicate :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to find a suitable duplicate of your question, but I only found real dupes which are based on the ancient `mysql_*` functions. The `mysql_*` functions (like the ones you are using) are no longer maintained by the PHP commuity (for some time now) and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)?

You should really try to pick up the better [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). Both of these option should be fine. Imho PDO has a better API, but `mysqli` is more towards mysql (in most cases PDO will do whatever you want to use it for).

With the two "new" API there is also the possibilty to use [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi). With prepared statements you should not have to worry about manually escaping values before inserting them into your queries.

An example of this using the PDO API would be:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=dbtest;host=127.0.0.1;charset=utf8', 'user', 'pass');

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM articleList WHERE user = :user');
$stmt->execute(array('user' => $user));
```

As you can see the values are not inserted directly into the query, but instead it uses placeholders. This code will make it impossible for people to inject arbitrary SQL into your query. And also you don't need to do any escaping anymore.

If you need more help in deciding between PDO or mysql check out [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) with more information about it. If you choose PDO you can find a good tutorial on the topic [here](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Thanks! Odd that w3schools would still have the old version.  http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: Don't you ever ever **ever** go to the site ever again. It's full of bad practices and is a terrible resource and it is one of the reason s people have vulnerable applications on the web. As a matter of fact on the topic of sql it **does** introduce SQL injection vulnerabilities and they refuse to fix their issues on the site.

Comment: w3schools is a wrong and misleading site. You shouldn't use it as reference for any sort of language. For PHP, there's the [PHP Manual](http://php.net), for JavaScript, there's [Mozilla Developer Network (or MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/). See http://w3fools.com to further understand why you should never use w3schools.

Answer (score 1):

Test this

```
$resultArticles = sprintf("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM articleList WHERE user='%s", 
mysql_real_escape_string($user));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just remove the escape characters:

```
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($user);
$resultArticles = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM articleList WHERE user = '$user'");
```

If you ever have trouble with variables, you can always just end the string and concatenate. I do this often to avoid confusion:

```
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($user);
$resultArticles = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM articleList WHERE user = '".$user."'");
```

As PeeHaa said, make sure you try to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Don't forget to escape all user input, or they potentially can destroy your database. If you are using MySQLi, you can use [mysqli::real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php). Sanitizing ALL your user data is absolutely essential. DO NOT SKIP THIS!

Comment: -1 for the second part.  Contencating SQL strings is BAD BAD BAD!! SQL Injection is still the king of all vulnerabilities, and encouraging people to code this way should be punishable by banisment!

Comment: I disagree with you 100%. Concatenation is NOT the problem here. If you sanitize the variables there is no problem.

Comment: Forgive me.  I may be a bit hysterical. The very last part of your answer corrected it for me.

Answer (score 0):

If the variable $user contains any special characters, it is necessary to escape these, as shown in the first answer. If you don't have the mysql_real_escape_string() function available, use addslashes().